# Assembly AT&T: movq %rdi, %rdx?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

AT&T x86 prime assembly,

I want to translate assembly

```
line 1: subq $8, %rsp 
line 2: movq %r11, (%rsp)
line 3: movq %rdi, %rdx
line 4: sarq $63, %rdx
line 5: movq %rdi,%rax
line 6: xorq %rdx,%rax
line 7: subq %rdx,%rax
line 8: movq (%rsp), %r11
line 9: add $8, %rsp
line 10: ret %r11
```

From what I *think* I understand, %rsp is the stackpointer, and the stackpointer here creates 8 bytes of space for a qword byte.

Could it look like this in C?

```
int main() {

    long x;

return 0:
}
```

What then happens at line 3 I'm not sure. I think the %rdi register goes into  %rdx. But how would this look like in C code? Nothing is tied to the register as I see it?

Hope someone can help me walk through line 1-3!

Comment: Right, from that much code we can't tell what the last line is doing. If it's the start of a function `rdi` holds the first argument, but `rdx` by itself doesn't give us any information about later intended use. PS: You probably made copy-paste error on line 2, that's presumably `movq $11, (%rsp)` which would then mean `long x = 11;` in your C code. There is no `return 0` in the assembly code.

Comment: Sorry Jester, added the whole part which we need to translate to C. it's part of an assignment, and I think (and wanted) to do the rest myself. So please don't spoil too much :D
It was %r11! Register. Sorry

Comment: What is “x86 prime assembly?”  I'm not sure what the “prime” refers to.

Comment: You again made some copy-paste errors, there is no `%rfx` and no `ret %r11` either. Anyway, `rdi` is the first argument which in case of `main` is `argc`.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry!!!

Comment: There's still no `ret %r11` instruction.  `ret` takes either no arg or an `imm16` to be added to RSP after popping the return address.  (For callee-pops conventions which x86-64 System V doesn't use.  And also, main won't have any stack args, they all fit in register).

Comment: Anyway, `sar` by reg width - 1 (to broadcast the sign bit to all bits) and XOR / SUB looks like an absolute-value idiom for a signed 2's complement integer.

Answer (score 0):

`mov %src_reg, %dst_reg` copies src to dst.  The `mov` instruction is always a copy.

RDI holds the first integer/pointer function arg, in the x86-64 System V calling convention.

---

`ret %r11` is illegal syntax.  There's no way you got that from a disassembler.

[`ret`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret) takes either no arg or an `imm16` to be added to RSP after popping the return address.  (For callee-pops conventions which x86-64 System V doesn't use.  And also, main won't have any stack args; they all fit in registers).

Anyway, `sar` by reg width - 1 (to broadcast the sign bit to all bits) and XOR / SUB looks like an absolute-value idiom for a signed 2's complement integer.

In this (and other) calling conventions, the return value is in RAX.  (Or for `int main`, in EAX.  But this function doesn't look like `main` unless it declared `long argc` instead of the standard `int`.)

So it could be `long foo(long x)` that returns the absolute value as well as storing to and reloading from a `volatile` local.  But IDK why the compiler would think there's anything useful in `%r11`.

It was clearly compiled with optimization enabled because it's not setting up RBP as a stack pointer, and with GCC or very old clang because it uses `sub $8,%rsp` instead of a dummy push.

Or maybe hand-written; that might be the only explanation for reading `%r11`.  Maybe a custom calling convention, not x86-64 System V after all?